# How to export GridView Excel/CSV format in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, excel, csv, export

How to export GridView Excel/CSV format in ASP.NET? I was searching code to export DataGrid data in Excel/CSV format, however didn't get the exact code. I manage to create the below one.

Answer (score -1):

you must fire an event or place a button named as Export to PDF. Upon this event please write the bellow code

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //To Export all pages
        GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
        this.BindGrid();

        GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
        {
            cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        }
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.BackColor = Color.White;
            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                }
                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
            }
        }

        GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

        //style to format numbers to string
        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        Response.Write(style);
        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

for further help. Please view https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-to-Excel-in-ASPNet-with-Formatting-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Please DO NOT recommend creating XLS, CSV files with `HtmlTextWriter` or `StringBuilder`. Use specialized libaries!